# Hooks: why do we need to VirtualProtect() again to restore permissions?

Tags: c++, winapi, x86, hook

Here is some standard piece of code where we install the hook rewriting some bytes at the beginning of the function of our interest. My question is: why do we need to reprotect a piece of rewrited memory? Can't we just leave it with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` permissions? We assume here that we need constantly restore original bytes and rehook again.

```
if (VirtualProtect(funcPtr, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwProtect)) // make memory writable
{
    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)funcPtr, Hook::origData, 6, 0); // save old data
    DWORD offset = ((DWORD)hook - (DWORD)funcPtr - 5);  //((to)-(from)-5)
    memcpy(&jmp[1], &offset, 4); // write address into jmp
    memcpy(Hook::hookData, jmp, 6); // save hook data
    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)funcPtr, jmp, 6, 0); // write jmp
    VirtualProtect(funcPtr, 6, dwProtect, NULL); // reprotect
}
```

Comment: Well, you don't.  As long as you are never successful at what you do.  That would make it too interesting for others to hack the program through the door you left opened.

Comment: @HansPassant, but what can stop others from to do the same, namely hook into this, VirtualProtect(), rewrite my (or original) bytes and VirtualProtect() back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once the door is open, anyone can walk through. If you've removed write-protection from a memory range, any code can update that memory - not just your code. The memory has no way of knowing that your (legitimate) code is the one updating it versus some possible malware or even just plain buggy DLL that is also loaded into the process space. Reprotecting it helps guard against not-your-code updating the memory locations you want to change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, David. Сontinuing the comparison with the door — if I know that it's me only who will walk through it, it seems that I can leave it opened? Are there any performance hits of constantly protecting/reprotecting the memory piece?

Comment: From a security perspective, `VirtualProtect` manages one layer of protection against bad/buggy code. It's up to you whether you need that layer. From a performance perspective, a function that is called always takes more time to execute than a function that is not called. Use profiling to see if you really get such a performance boost that it's worth considering not having the layer of protection.